# CSS file Not Working in Node JS getting Error

Tags: html, css, node.js, express

App Directory

```
/Project
/server
   /app.js
   /Router
      /auth.js
   /static
      /css
          /style.css
     /img
         /image1.png  
  /views
    /index.ejs
```

code in Node JS (app.js) file

`app.use("static", express.static("static"));`

code in Index.ejs file stored inside views folder

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/style.css" >`

Page loading Succesfully but Without CSS and images

I tried to modify
code in NodeJs File with following block

`app.use("../static", express.static("static"));`

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use(express.static('static'))
```

for using at client
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" >`
when you make a request it directly send request to the static folder

Comment: Not Helping out with problem